# Postgres filtering by tstzrange not ended

Tags: postgresql

I have a trigger function using a temporal postgres table. Which is versioned by a 'sys_period' variable defined as a tstzrange. I can see my trigger fails since it does not approriate filter only the active rows in the table.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_analysis_{0}_function()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE analysis
    SET finish_date = (
        SELECT STRICT_MAX(performed_on)
        FROM task
        WHERE analysis_id = NEW.analysis_id 
        )
    WHERE id = NEW.analysis_id;
    return NEW;
END;
$$;
CREATE TRIGGER update_analysis_{0}
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF performed_on
    ON task
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_analysis_{0}_function();
```

Both the analysis table and the task table has versioning with sysperiod. (The strict_max is from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_strict_min_and_max)

The current version gets bugs which could be fixed if I could filter on sys_period not ended. making the body look something like this:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE analysis
    SET finish_date = (
        SELECT STRICT_MAX(performed_on)
        FROM task
        WHERE analysis_id = NEW.analysis_id 
        AND task.sys_period.end = NULL
        )
    WHERE id = NEW.analysis_id;
    AND Analysis.sys_period.end = NULL
    return NEW;
END;
```

Comment: Can you please add your table structure, along with expected input and output?  I'm not entirely sure what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

The function I was looking for was upper_inf. Giving the following solution:

```
 UPDATE analysis
    SET finish_date = (
        SELECT STRICT_MAX(performed_on)
        FROM task
        WHERE analysis_id = NEW.analysis_id 
        AND upper_inf(task.sys_period)
        )
    WHERE id = NEW.analysis_id;
    AND upper_inf(task.sys_period)
    return NEW;
END;
```